# How to Pause an activity with Button Click?

Tags: android

I want to pause an animation activity with button click, here i have one ball which is falling from top to bottom animation. I want one button "stop" which pauses the fall in between and record its x,y position.

Comment: This honestly depends on how the ball is animated.

Comment: Create a method which stops animation of falling ball. And call the method on button click.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition in your ball animation such that

```
while(buttonPressed == false && //whatever other code you need for the animation to run)
{
    //button animation code here
}
```

and then have an if statement after it, with the condition being that if the buttonPressed is true, that will record the position of the ball. You can set the buttonPressed boolean to be true by using an action listener added to your stop button.

Answer (score 0):

Put this first:

```
    AnimatorSet set;
    img_logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_logo);
    set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.anim.flipping);
    set.setTarget(img_logo);
    set.start();
```

On Button Click:

```
set.stop();
```

I think this could also help you--->http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/01/start-and-stop-frame-animation-with.html